# Is it possible to add multiple instances in Django?

Tags: python, django

In the image, I have the standard class with product, price, vendor, etc. I am wondering if it's possible to be able to add multiple products. I used MSPaint to give out details of what I am talking about. Basically the customer could make an order, but it would have the option of having 1, 5, 10, or unlimited amount of products in it. Is this possible? What would be the best way to approach this? Is there a better way to approach this than my image?

[image: model]

Answer (score 2):

Read more about [Foreign keys in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Comment: I talked with one of my co-workers and he suggesed a ManyToMany relationship in Purchase Order linking to another class which has orders and do an inline. Would this work?

Comment: It would definitely work. It is even a better solution if you want to be able to add the same product into different purchase orders, which is the case. So using a many to many relation ship is the way to go. I also suggest adding blank=True and null=True in case you want to create a purchase order and save it before adding any products to it.

    products = Models.manyToManyField('Product', null=True, blank=True)

You can access an order's products using 

    order.products.all()

Comment: Would I add inline too? Or Once I do the ManyToMany field will it automatically have the option for "add another product" to this?

Comment: It would be automatically generated in the admin tool, not sure if it would be the same for django forms.

Answer (score 0):

foreign Key relationship between Order and the OrderItem and relationship between User and Order.

Comment: I talked with one of my co-workers and he suggesed a ManyToMany relationship in Purchase Order linking to another class which has orders and do an inline. Would this work?

Comment: sure , it should works. try it. but with the foreign key relation between models it keeps things distinct. for example one order should should be related to only one user. thing about that.